# A very difficult Diophantine problem $n^2 \mid 3^n+2^n+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, conjectures

> Prove that $n=3$ is the only positive integer greater than $1$, for which$$n^2 \mid 3^n+2^n+1.$$

This is a conjecture.

Comment: Conjecture checked for $n\leq 100000$ (only solutions $n=1$ and $3$).

Comment: If $ n $ is even, then $ 4 \mid n^2 \mid 3^n + 2^n + 1 \implies 4 \mid 3^n + 1 $. But for $ n $ even, $ 3^n \equiv 1 \pmod 4 $, a contradiction.

Comment: Holds for $n\le 10\,000\,000$.

Comment: Just to state the obvious: if $n$ is a prime $>7$, the RHS is $\equiv 6\pmod{p}$, hence $n \nmid RHS $.

Comment: Ghartal, where did you get this??????

Comment: I made it myself!

Answer (score 4):

Worth an answer. It is fairly likely that there is no known solution for this. Several years ago we had some nonsense with the similar $$(n^2 - 1) | (3^n + 5^n)$$

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16341/on-polynomials-dividing-exponentials

I admit, the question here differs in a way that may be important, as the analogous MO problem would be $$n^2 | (1 + 3^n + 5^n)$$

The same question was asked here, [Find all positive integers $n$ s.t. $3^n + 5^n$ is divisible by $n^2 - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612346/find-all-positive-integers-n-s-t-3n-5n-is-divisible-by-n2-1) 
Gottfried put in a good deal of effort, however, if you check his comments below his answer, he realizes that he does not have a complete proof, although there are places inside the answer that claim completeness.

Comment: I think I saw a complete solution to the MO problem on SE! I can't find it now! edit: I found it: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612346/find-all-positive-integers-n-s-t-3n-5n-is-divisible-by-n2-1/773330#773330)!

Comment: Yes, I rechecked it, it is not complete yet.